# Define the direction of the component resize

Tags: apache-flex

I have three component in the Hgroup and all three component can expand. But the problem is, all three component expansion to the right direction. and the container dont have enough space to do that, so what I need is

the first one expansion to the right

the second one expansion to the right and left

the third one expansion to the left.

and others will be push away in the process.

like this.

[image: like this]

But how can I define the component's expansion direction?

The component's code is like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width.State2="500" height.State2="550"
         width.State1="330" height.State1="550">



    <s:states>
        <s:State name="State1"/>
        <s:State name="State2"/>
    </s:states>



    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <mx:LinkButton includeIn="State1" x="222" y="519" label="Expand" click="currentState='State2'"/>
    <mx:LinkButton includeIn="State2" x="433" y="519" label="Return"
                   click="currentState='State1'"/>
</s:Group>
```

and in the main comp, three of those Comp will be nest in the HGroup

```
<s:HGroup  x="90" y="62" width="1000" height="550">
    <ns1:comp1>
    </ns1:comp1>
    <ns1:comp2>
    </ns1:comp2>
    <ns1:comp3>
    </ns1:comp3>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: What does "all three components can expand" mean?  How do they expand?  When do they expand?  Is this code you have written or are you using generic HGroups?

Comment: expand mean the length of the components can expand. And I am using generic HGroups. How can I define the direction of the component's expansion?

Comment: What 'component' is that? Is it an existing component or a custom one? If custom, how does it expand? Show some code.

Comment: an existing component. it have two stage 1 and 2. the stage 2 have a larger length then stage 1. and three of this components placed in a Hgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way would be with states.

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="1Expanded"/>
    <s:State name="2Expanded"/>
    <s:State name="3Expanded"/>
</s:states>
```

then in your components:

```
<ns1:comp1
    width="250"
    width.1Expanded="500"
    width.2Expanded="100"
    width.3Expanded="50">
```

you can adjust these to fit what you need, but that was an example.

Comment: Thanks, may be the easiest way is to nest the comps in a comp. Actually, I was thinking can I set up some kind of base line for the comp to expand.

Comment: yeah, that answer was a quickie.  Consider also that the comps will probably want to lay out subcomponents differently depending on size.  So it's likely you will actually want to change the state of the components rather than the properties as I showed in the simple example above.